How to construct a tuple with a superset of types from tuples with non-overlapping subset of types
Suppose I have a tuple-like that is essentially a wrapper around std::tuple (so a solution for std::tuple works too). How would I go writing a constructor/tuple_cat equivalent that can take an arbitrary amount of arguments of the same templated type but with each having a subset of the template arguments of the return.
The problem with just using std::tuple_cat is that the return type is based on arguments. What I would like to do is have a fixed return type, so that any member not passed in inside a tuple would be default-constructed. It also allows for duplicate types while I would like to error or any overlap in type arguments to the arguments. Ordering is preserved too
An example of what I mean, the constraints in comments are enforced by requires clauses
template<typename... Ts>
// Ts constrained to only one of each type
struct MyTuple {
    template<typename... Tuples>
    // Tuples constrained to all be instantiations of MyTuple
    // each Tuples<Us...> constrained that Us is strictly a subset of types in Ts
    // every pair of Tuples<Us...> constrained to not have any overlap in their Us
    // const& used for simplicity to not get into std::forward-ing everything
    MyTuple(Tuples const&... args)
    {
        // no clue
        // using initializer list would be better, but even less of a clue on that
    }

    std::tuple<Ts...> mTuple;
}

Usage would be something like:
// A..E are default constructible, distinct types
using SuperTuple = MyTuple<A, B, C, D, E>;
// A, B, C and E are passed in as arguments, D is default-constructed
auto super = SuperTuple{MyTuple<A>{}, MyTuple<E,B>{}, MyTuple<C>{}};

Is this even possible?

This is no different than a copy/paste of the homework question. What have you tried so far? Did you try adding atleast some of the requires clauses.

For each tuple, for each type call get<T>(mTuple) = get<T>(otherTuple).

@Alan How did you know this is a homework question?

@Alan It is not a copy paste. I have not added the requires clauses on purpose because they would needlessly extend the question. The important thing is the fact that they are present and what they do. So any answer need not to concern itself with eg. handling duplicate types. I have tried tuple_cat and described why it does not fit. I have tried the suggestion of @Osyotr, unfolding the Ts first, then Tuples then checking in if constexpr if the jth Tuple has ith type, then std::geting it from it. That runs the default ctor for all Ts then assigns them, not only when needed

"they would needlessly extend the question..." No they won't. Instead, they will show that you've made an attempt to solve your question.

Here's an implementation that

Doesn't default construct unnecessary elements
Forwards correctly

The difficulty in your requirements lie in how the std::tuple constructor must have the correct arity. To remedy that, we create an "identity" type default_construct_t that does the right thing when we're missing an argument, similar to how 0 is the identity for sums.
To avoid recursion or a large amount of metaprogramming trying to index into the pack of tuples, we conveniently reuse default_construct_t to fold across types in std::common_type_t.
#include<tuple>
#include<utility>

struct default_construct_t
{
    using type = default_construct_t;

    template<typename T>
    operator T() { return T(); }
};

template<typename, typename>
struct has_element : std::false_type
{
};

template<typename... Args, typename T>
requires ((std::is_same_v<T, Args> || ...))
struct has_element<std::tuple<Args...>, T>
    : std::true_type
{
};

template<typename Tup, typename T>
concept contains = has_element<std::decay_t<Tup>, T>::value;

template<typename T, typename... Tuples>
decltype(auto) find(Tuples&&... tuples)
{
    using R = std::common_type_t<
        std::conditional_t<
            contains<decltype(tuples), T>,
            std::type_identity<decltype(tuples)>,
            default_construct_t
        >...
    >::type;

    if constexpr(std::is_same_v<R, default_construct_t>)
        return default_construct_t{};
    else
        return std::get<T>(std::get<R>(
            std::forward_as_tuple(std::forward<Tuples>(tuples)...)
        ));
}

template<typename... Ts>
struct MyTuple
{
    template<typename... Tuples>
    MyTuple(Tuples&&... tuples)
        : mTuple{find<Ts>(std::forward<Tuples>(tuples)...)...}
    {
    }

    std::tuple<Ts...> mTuple;
};

Live.

I'm going to assume as part of writing your constraints, you have a trait or concept tuple_contains<T, Tuple> that checks if the tuple Tuple has an element of the type T.
What you need to do is construct the cartesian product of your parameter packs. This can be done with a helper function for each level of expansion.
template <typename TupleIn, typename TupleOut, typename T>
void assign_impl_inner(const TupleIn& in, TupleOut& out) {
    if constexpr(tuple_contains<T, TupleIn>) {
        get<T>(out) = get<T>(in);
    }
}

template <typename TupleIn, typename TupleOut, typename... Ts>
void assign_impl(const TupleIn& in, TupleOut& out) {
    (assign_impl_inner<TupleIn, TupleOut, Ts>(in, out), ...);
}

template<typename... Ts>
// Ts constrained to only one of each type
struct MyTuple {
    template<typename... Tuples>
    // Tuples constrained to all be instantiations of MyTuple
    // each Tuples<Us...> constrained that Us is strictly a subset of types in Ts
    // every pair of Tuples<Us...> constrained to not have any overlap in their Us
    // const& used for simplicity to not get into std::forward-ing everything
    MyTuple(Tuples const&... args)
    {
        (assign_impl<Tuples, std::tuple<Ts...>, Ts...>(args, mTuple), ...);
    }

    std::tuple<Ts...> mTuple;
};

See it on coliru
